# Angular 9+ PWA fingerprint/faceid integration

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps, capacitor

I am going to create Angular 9+ PWA application, for mobile friendly user experience purposes.

If user opens app in a phone that has fingerprint/faceid sensors I want to replace username/password authentication with fingerprint/faceid.

I know that just pwa can't access mobile sensors, but is there any workeraoud? for example ionic-capacitor framework

Answer (score 3):

> [cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fingerprint-aio)

This cordova plugin supports both fingerprint and FaceID and also works with capacitor.

There is also a guide available on ionic website [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/fingerprint-aio).

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is for Native apps. Not for PWA.

Answer (score 0):

There is a capacitor plugin: capacitor-native-biometric

- [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-native-biometric)

This is also possible on the web (in case you use the app as a pwa app also)

Example:

```
 PublicKeyCredential
  .isUserVerifyingPlatformAuthenticatorAvailable()
  .then((availableOrNot) => {
    console.log(availableOrNot)
  });
```

This should indicate if a user-verifying platform authenticator is available.

- Touch ID or Face ID (macOS and iOS)
- Windows Hello (Windows)
- Device unlock (fingerprint, face, PIN, etc.) on Android